# Access to element on another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a `TabActivity` with two tabs-activities — `FirstActivity` and `SecondActivity`.

How can I access to any element (for example, change `TextView`'s text) on `FirstActivity` from `SecondActivity`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access them directly. You either inherit them from the same class, and use the parent's class methods to communicate between them, but I am recommending to use a broadcast from the sender and a broadcastreceiver on the receiver activity. You can use putExtra to transfer details with the intent.